# Why apt would not downgrade a package

Tags: linux, package-management, apt

I have some package that I want to manually downgrade. If I run `apt-cache policy`, I see the needed version:

```
$ apt-cache policy foo-package | head
foo-package:
  Installed: 0.21.0-0
  Candidate: 0.21.0-0
  Version table:
 *** 0.21.0-0 0
        500 ***/ unstable/all/ Packages
        100 ***
     0.20.0-0 0
        500 ***/ unstable/all/ Packages
     0.19.0-0 0
```

However, if I try to manually downgrade it, it does not work:

```
$ apt-get install foo-package=0.20.0-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  foo-package
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
```

The output of `apt-cache policy` does not change after this.

Manually removing and after that installing the package (`apt-get remove foo-package; apt-get install foo-package=0.20.0-0`) does work (though removes some packages that require `foo-package=0.21.0-0`, but I'm ok with that).

There are no held packages: `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` prints nothing.

What can be a reason for this? Is there some apt option that can be responsible for such behavior?

(In fact, we have unusual installation (not any of standard distributions), so it may be a reason. But I'd like to know whether such behavior can be explained by some standard settings of apt.)

Comment: It's a design flaw, apt is rotten to the core, no work can be done to salvage it